QGIS: data offset issues when loading different coordinate systems


Set the project coordinate system to EPSG:4326, load OSM's WMTS data with EPSG:3857, and load an SHP file with EPSG:4551. When the WMTS is at different zoom levels, the position of the SHP data on the WMTS varies, as shown in the figure.

The "project on the fly" capability of GIS is predicated on correct metadata. You have three different projections at play, and it's unclear what is being defined where and when. Please [Edit] the Question to include coordinate values associated with the different datasets, and how each layer (and canvas) is defined.

Why set project CRS to EPSG:4326 when neither the tiles nor the SHP is in that CRS? What happens when you set the project CRS to EPSG:3857?

Because I want to test how QGIS handles when the coordinate system of the engineering coordinate system and the actual loaded data are different, I have come to the conclusion that it will dynamically convert the data into the engineering coordinate system and then draw it. But what I don't understand is why the OSM map tiles behave differently at different levels when the engineering coordinate system is 4326, as shown in the image in the problem.

Your WMTS layer as such looks nominal displayed in a EPSG:4326 project. As mentioned before, to get further help, share details about your .shp data. I would tend to assume the issue come from there.
